# "ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0" in log when item in RecyclerView is tapped?

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

In my app I am creating, I have a list of items. When a user taps on one of these items, a new window is supposed to open, displaying the information inside the item that the user tapped on. Here is my java code for that-

**NoteListFragment.java**

```
public class NoteListFragment extends Fragment {

private FloatingActionButton mFab;
private View mRootView;
private List<Note> mNotes;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private NoteListAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


public NoteListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment and hold the reference
    //in mRootView
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_list, container, false);

    //Get a programmatic reference to the Floating Action Button
    mFab = (FloatingActionButton)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    //attach an onClick listener to the Floating Action Button
    mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class));
        }
    });

    setupList();
    return mRootView;
}


private void setupList() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.note_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector =
            new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child);
                Note selectedNote = mNotes.get(position);
                Intent editorIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
                editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId());
            }
            System.out.print("Failed to load Editor class.");
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });

    mAdapter = new NoteListAdapter(mNotes, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mNotes = NoteManager.newInstance(getActivity()).getAllNotes();
}

}
```

**NoteEditorActivity.java**

```
public class NoteEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //remove this line in the MainActivity.java

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("id")){
            long id = args.getLong("id", 0);
            if (id > 0){
                openFragment(NotePlainEditorFragment.newInstance(id), "Editor");
            }
        }
        openFragment(NotePlainEditorFragment.newInstance(0), "Editor");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_note_editor, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment, String title){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
}
```

For some reason, when I tap one of the items, nothing happens, and the log says

```
11-26 09:45:17.963 12963-12963/com.example.simplenotepad D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-26 09:45:18.073 12963-12963/com.example.simplenotepad D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

What does this mean? How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the activity in the RecyclerView on touch event.

The code with the correction is:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

        if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child);
            Note selectedNote = mNotes.get(position);
            Intent editorIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
            editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId());
            startActivity(editorIntent);
        }
        System.out.print("Failed to load Editor class.");
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Now the editor screen does come up, but it doesn't display any information. You did answer my question though.

Comment: @GeorgeB if It is not showing, the problem is in the NoteEditorActivity. Can you post the code of NoteEditorActivity?

Comment: I've posted it in the question now

Comment: @GeorgeB the id of selected node is a long? Can you debug or add logs to see if the args from intent are ok?